# Visitor pattern with Java 8 default methods

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, default-method

[Visitor pattern (double dispatch)](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) is a very useful pattern in its own rights, but it has often been scrutinized of breaking interfaces if any new member is added to the inheritance hierarchy, which is a valid point.

But after the introduction of default methods in Java 8, now that we can define default implementation in interfaces, the client interfaces will not break and clients can gracefully adopt the changed interface as appropriate.

```
interface Visitor{
   public void visit(Type1 type);
   public void visit(Type2 type);

   //added after the first version of visitor is released
   default public void visit(NewType type){
        //some default implementation
   }
}
```

Now with default methods no more breakage of client code if new type `NewType` is introduced in future.

Does this make Visitor more adoptable and useful?

Comment: I personally see the interface break as an advantage, most of the time, because it forces you to take care of the new type everywhere, without fearing to miss a place like you would with chains of instanceof tests. Implementing the new visit() method as a default method would provide a default implementation which, I guess, would be wrong in 99% of the cases. Who cares if the code still compiles, if you know it won't do what it should at runtime?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. Its just that visitor has this one disadvantage which I thought was no more applicable. But I see why one should not use default method with visitor.

Comment: I agree, the Visitor Pattern is IMO all about compile errors. If the code breaks not before runtime, aka. at the customer's, it is too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question contains the implicit assertion that a *Visitor* has to be an `interface`. Since the *Visitor* pattern is not Java specific, it does not mandate such an implementation.

In fact, there are a lot of uses around the world using an `abstract` class for the *Visitor* or using an `interface` but providing an `abstract` implementation class at the same time.

While [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737127/visitor-pattern-with-java-8-default-methods#comment34655132_22737127) has a valid point of the possibility to detect unhandled cases at compile time this applies only to the case where every visitor always has to provide implementations for every `visit` method. This can be quite a code bloat when you have a lot of cases (And may cause other developers to write their own `abstract` base class for their visitors).

As said, not everyone uses the *Visitor* pattern this way. A lot of implementations use `abstract` classes for providing empty `visit` methods or `visit` methods which delegate to another `visit` method taking a more abstract type. For these implementations, adding a new type never was an issue.

And, to answer your question, when using the *Visitor* pattern in a way not forcing every *Visitor* to provide an implementation for every method, using `default` methods in interfaces is an option. But it does not make the *Visitor* pattern “more adoptable and useful” as there never was a real problem with it. The option to use an `abstract` visitor class always existed.